# Testing JavaScript views in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bdd, konacha

What is the best way to test JavaScript views (test to see if a page works JavaScript wise) in Rails?

So lets say I have a page called `/users/new` that contains a form that does something. I would like to have it so that I submit the form and the JavaScript testing tool will let me know if that page breaks or not. What is the best way to do this?

I have come across three options for testing:

1. **Konacha** (best tool so far for JS BDD) http://www.solitr.com/blog/2012/04/konacha-tutorial-javascript-testing-with-rails/
2. **JasmineRice** (Jasmine + Rails + Guard) https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice/
3. **Capybara** Webkit. https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit

The first two are basically there for **BDD** and isolated testing. The last one is more for what I'm looking for, but **I don't want to have a separate testing setup for JavaScript BDD and integration testing**.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using RSpec, you can use Capybara in an RSpec integration test:

```
spec/requests/my_spec.rb:

describe "my test", :js => true do
  it "should do something" do
    visit '/some/path'

    click_on 'Submit'

    page.should have_content 'Congratulations!'
  end
end
```

Remember to set `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit` in `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: This is what we do for a rather large application. It works, but is *very* slow. You only really want to do this where you absolutely need to.

Answer (score 8):

Check the Teaspoon Project on github.

https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon

It supports Mocha, Jasmine, and QUnit.. has nice support for running your specs headlessly with PhantomJS (or Selenium Webdriver), and allows using the full Rails asset pipeline (coffeescript, fixtures, etc).

Also, it was heavily influenced by my experience with other test runners using Rails.

Comment: +1 for Teaspoon. I really like its coverage support.